# how to trigger event when data changed in R3 Corda Node

Tags: corda

On our project, I store some data on block chain, my question is how can get to know when these data changed.(so that we can send emails, sms, web notifications to end user)

the first thought were list as below, but it seems either of them were best choice

1. query database every few seconds. Very stupid way, but it seems can be worked.
2. using one RPC interceptor, and check all the things send to node.
3. using flows, subflows
4. using schedule service
   do you have any good ieads about this, please kindly reply me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a few points, there is no "real" blockchain on Corda, there are consumed/unconsumed states, I think you should reformulate  a bit better your question, do you want to be notified when a states get consumed? When a new state is created? Try to explain in "Corda" terms :D

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes, you are right, my purpose is get notified when a states get consumed.It better on both side, include Initiator and acceptor. Do you get any ideas about that, thanks.